# Keytab file: /path/a.keytab does not exist

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have keytab file in local directory , path. I am trying to pass this keytab and principal via `--keytab` and `--principal in <spark-opts>` in oozie. However I am getting error ***Keytab file: /path/a.keytab*** does not exist . However the file exists in path directory. What could be issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With oozie, you have to put the keytab in the lib directory of your workflow stored in HDFS. Then, your spark action should be able to read it.